# What is this type of design called?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, designers

[image: What is this type of design called]
What is this type of design called ?

Comment: You ended up with the answer you wanted, but it would have been better if you had clarified in your question what aspect of the image you're inquiring about. (For example: "What is this type of 3D-ish look called?")

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These type of illustrations are known as isometric illustrations, can design these easily on Adobe Illustrator with the help of Isometric grid, which can be downloaded here [Isometric grid](http://taylorhokanson.com/2014/09/29/accurate-isometric-grid-template-for-illustrator/).

Isometric projection is a method for visually representing three-dimensional objects in two dimensions.

Comment: Probably worth adding that they are useful in engineering contexts due as the lines along each axis are the same scale - e.g. so the outside of a cube appears to be hexagonal ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rue7b.jpg))